# C# Background Worker Append TextBox

Tags: c#

first off I'd like to say I'm brand new to C# so I am not too aware with how the background worker is supposed to be implemented. I have a GUI program that basically pings a domain a returns the response to a textbox. I am able to get it to work normally, however, it freezes the code because it is running on the same thread which is why I am trying to implement a background worker.
Here is the basic setup

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    url = textBox1.Text;
    button1.Enabled = false;
    button2.Enabled = true;
    bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorker_DoWork);
    bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

}
private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    do
    {
        if (bgWorker.CancellationPending)
            break;

        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { monitor(); });

    } while (true);
}
public void monitor()
{
    textBox2.AppendText("Status of: " + url + "\n");
    Status(url);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
}
private void Status(string url)
{
    // This method does all the ping work and also appends the status to the Text box as it goes through , as OK or down
}
```

I have not worked with bgworkers before and as you can imagine it's confusing. I've looked at tons of other articles and I can't seem to get it. Sorry if the code looks crazy, I'm trying to learn.

Comment: Does the code work or not?  Do-Loops are really fast, so your code is just pummeling the TextBox with string updates faster than it can handle.  Don't do that.  Pings usually work better on a timer with a reasonable interval.

Comment: It does work. I have it to set the thread to sleep at an interval of 30000

Comment: I don't see that code.

Comment: I apologize, it was removed at the time of copy because I am trying to get it to work, so I am moving a lot around. In monitor right under status is System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);

Comment: The question has an edit link underneath it.  Update it appropriately.  It sounds like you have sleep running on the UI thread, hence why the form is locking up.

Comment: Can you paste your ping code, as it will be easier to get you a complete solution

Comment: Your `do { ... } while (true)` loop would be killing your CPU and the call to `monitor` is killing the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

You've got several mistakes. First,

```
Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    monitor();
});
```

will call `monitor()` on your UI thread. In almost all cases you should not call methods on other threads. You especially should not call methods that block or do anything that takes more than a few milliseconds on your UI thread, and that is what this does:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
```

Instead of calling a method on another thread; submit immutable data to the other thread and let the thread decide when to handle it. There is an event already built in to BackgroundWorker which does that. Before you call `bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync()` do this:

```
url = new Uri(something);
bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
bgWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
bgWorker.ProgressChanged += Bgw_ProgressChanged;


private void Bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.AppendText("Status of: " + url + ": " + e.UserState.ToString()
        + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Your `bgWorker_DoWork` should look more like this:

```
void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (!bgw.CancellationPending)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
        var status = ResultOfPing(e.Argument as Uri);
        bgw.ReportProgress(0, status);
    }

    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

and you should call it like this:

```
bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(url);
```

You've got a second problem. BackgroundWorker creates a thread, and your thread is going to spend most of its time blocked on a timer or waiting for network responses. That is a poor use of a thread. You would be better off using completion callbacks or [async/await](http://msdn.com/async).

Answer (score 1):

Use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "System.Reactive.Windows.Forms" and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;`) and then you can do this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var url = textBox1.Text;
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.5))
        .SelectMany(_ => Observable.Start(() => Status(url)))
        .ObserveOn(this)
        .Subscribe(status => textBox2.AppendText("Status of: " + status + "\n"));
}
```

You then just need to change `Status` to have this signature: `string Status(string url)`.

That's it. No background worker. No invoking. And `Status` is nicely run on a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

The background worker is running on a thread pool thread, but your call to Status and Sleep is running on the UI thread.  You need to move that stuff back into bgWorker_DoWork.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool cancel;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void StartPinging()
    {
        this.cancel = false;
        startButton.Enabled = false;
        stopButton.Enabled = true;
        responseBox.Clear();
        responseBox.AppendText("Starting to ping server.");
        responseBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        var bw = new BackgroundWorker
        {
            WorkerReportsProgress = false,
            WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
        };
        bw.DoWork += (obj, ev) =>
        {
            while (!cancel)
            {
                // Ping Server Here
                string response = Server.PingServer();

                this.Invoke(new UiMethod(() =>
                {
                    responseBox.AppendText(response);
                    responseBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                }));
            }
        };

        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (obj, ev) =>
        {
            this.Invoke(new UiMethod(() =>
            {
                responseBox.AppendText("Stopped pinging the server.");
                responseBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                startButton.Enabled = true;
                stopButton.Enabled = false;
            }));
        };

        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    delegate void UiMethod();


    private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartPinging();
    }

    private void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        responseBox.AppendText("Cancelation Pressed.");
        responseBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        cancel = true;
    }
}

public class Server
{
    static Random rng = new Random();
    public static string PingServer()
    {
        int time = 1200 + rng.Next(2400);
        Thread.Sleep(time);
        return $"{time} ms";
    }
}
```

[image: scr]

Answer (score -1):

Erwin, when dealing with C# - threads and UI elements usually you will come across cross-thread operations i.e. Background thread with UI threads. This interaction needs to be done in thread safe way with the help of Invoke to avoid invalid operations.

Please look into below resource:  InvokeRequired section.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls

Comment: Why has this been downgraded? Please respond, so I can improve.

Comment: Not your downvoter, but the question does not claim to have a cross-thread issue.  The code is calling Invoke already in the DoWork method.

Comment: Yeah threading isnt the problem here, its the implimentation of the constant ping and thread sleeping on the ui (is my gut feel)